# Extract SensorEvent in JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, sensors

I am newbie in JNI programming. I want to do a sensorEvent **parse** job in JNI to get **sensorEvent.values** in the **float arrays format**.

But I don't know how to extract the **jobject sensorEvent** to get **sensorEvent.values** on JNI?

```
// JAVA
public class MySensor {

    // load native dll
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("example"); 
    }

    // this native function will be call by onSensorChanged()
    private native void parse(SensorEvent sensorEvent); 

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent != null) {

            // content of sensorEvent.values is
            //   sensorEvent.values[0] = 1.0f
            //   sensorEvent.values[1] = 1.1f
            //   sensorEvent.values[1] = 1.2f               
            parse(sensorEvent);     // do this job in JNI
        }
    }

}

// JNI
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_company_MySensor_parse(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jobject sensorEvent) {

    // how to extract sensorEvent to get sensorEvent.values and show values?     
    //??? 

    printf("SensorEvent.values[0]= %f", sensorEvent.values[0]); // 1.0f
    printf("SensorEvent.values[1]= %f", sensorEvent.values[1]); // 1.1f
    printf("SensorEvent.values[2]= %f", sensorEvent.values[2]); // 1.2f
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? Why won't you user sensorEvent.values as an input for you native function or why won't you parse the values on java side? Working with java object in native code forces you to write much more code in order to stay safe & doesn't improve performance.

Comment: `GetObjectClass`, `GetFieldID`, `GetFloatField`. Consult [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: @DmitriiZ I want to hide the sensor calculation process in JNI because the data released by the sensor is still raw (cannot be read directly). You are right, the program becomes a bit slow when using jni on android.

Comment: @Michael, Thankyou for point out. My problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on information from @Michael, I was able to find the answer. Thank You All.

```
const char *CLS_SENSOR_EVENT = "android/hardware/SensorEvent";
const char *FLD_VALUES = "values";
const char *SIG_VALUES = "[F";

jfloat getSensorValue(JNIEnv *env, jobject sensorEvent) {
    jboolean* isCopy = JNI_FALSE;

    jclass clsSensorEvent = env->FindClass(CLS_SENSOR_EVENT);
    if (NULL == clsSensorEvent) {
        return -1;
    }
    jfieldID fldValues = env->GetFieldID(clsSensorEvent, FLD_VALUES, SIG_VALUES);
    if (NULL == fldValues) {
        return -1;
    }
    jobject objValues = env->GetObjectField(sensorEvent, fldValues);
    if (NULL == objValues) {
        return -1;
    }

    jfloatArray floArrValues = reinterpret_cast<jfloatArray>(objValues);
    jfloat *flo = env->GetFloatArrayElements(floArrValues, isCopy);
    if (NULL == *flo) {
        return -1;
    }
    jfloat result = flo[0];
    env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(floArrValues, flo, 0);
    return result;
}
```